# When getting latest what exactly does "Getting" mean

Tags: tfs, tfvc

In the output window some lines say "Getting" and some say "Replacing". Is "Getting" just informing you that it is checking out files you are already working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Latest Version works in a check list method, means that **when it gets a file** from the server to your local file system it writes down the file and its version, **it will not get that file again until the file version will be changed on the server**.

In case you made local changes and changes have been made on the server the Get Latest Version will trigger the merge window in order to **merge your local changes with the server changes**. (Replacing)

---

This is due to  your local workspace already have some source controlled files in TFS but with different version.

So when you get latest it will **replaced** the version you have in local. If you want to avoid this behavior, you could either back up your local files in the workspace first or directly create a new workspace and get latest there. Then you will not see those lines say "Replacing".

Beside, below is also a possibility:

> When you get files and folders from the server, the system also
>   deletes any checked-in files from your local workspace that have been
>   deleted from the server. **Files that have been renamed or moved on
>   the server are changed in your workspace to match the changes on the
>   server.**

More details please refer this link in MSDN: [Download (get) files from the Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server)

Comment: TFS could not judge if  the files are you created or not during the get  operation. It will just compare the versions  between local and server. Besides,  in Source Control Explorer you can verify whether you have the latest version of a file in the **Latest** column. You can see specific version information about an item by opening its shortcut menu and choosing Properties.

Comment: Just to clarify... what if I added a new file in Visual Studio and checked it in. I was the only person who ever edited this file, and only from the original machine I created it on. Under those assumptions, is there any circumstance under which you would expect the output window to say it was getting that file? This is the scenario I "believe" has happened. Perhaps I am mistaken on some point about the reality of events but I'll keep an eye out and see if it happens again.

Comment: @BVernon Based on your assumptions, the answer is no. If you simply get that file from TFS server, you will got a prompt message:`All files are up to date. No files were updated because the requested file versions were previously downloaded` Just as the message described, the file versions were downloaded previously, no need to download/get again. However, like you said, the reality of events are not 100% the same as the assumption, for example maybe there are something changed in your local workspace caused that situation. Suggest you keep an eye out if it occurs again.

Comment: Two points: 1) In my case it still wouldn't have said files were up to date because there were other changes, but I realize that shouldn't make a difference in regard to the issue at hand. 2) But you mention "the file versions were downloaded previously". Not so sure about that?? I was the one who created the files and checked them in. So are you saying that it always has to "get" the files even after you check them in even if only to replace the exact same copy of the file you just checked in?

Comment: Or maybe you are just referring to all "other" files having already been downloaded.

Comment: @BVernon "the file versions were downloaded previously" It's just the prompt message info in Visual Studio if you try to get latest, but locals are already have the latest version, even so you are the man who created the files locally and just check in TFS, didn't pull down any versions from TFS server. It will still return this message, as I said before. TFS could not judge whether the files are you created or download from server. It will only compare local versions with server versions to judge it is latest or not.

Comment: @BVernon Besides, I think you don't have to pay so much attention to what the output message indicated, the limited info could not stand for varieties of  situations. To sum up saying, if only you were the only person who ever edited this file, and only from the original machine you created it on. No others committed code to that branch/ folder. No matter you pull latest from TFS sever, or you check in local changes to TFS server, both of the scenarios , you will not have to solve any conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says. "Getting" indicates it's a new file and it's being downloaded for the first time. "Replacing" indicates it's a changed file.

Comment: Hmm... that's what I would have thought except that it said getting on a lot of files I created and was the one who checked in to begin with so didn't make sense to me why they were showing up as "getting" when I'm the only one who ever worked on them and only from one machine. Weird.